# Fast string splitting in MATLAB

Tags: performance, matlab, split

I've been using MATLAB to read through a bunch of output files and have noticed that it was reading the files fairly slowly in comparison to a reader that I wrote in Python for the same files (on the order of 120s for MATLAB, 4s for Python on the same set). The files have a combination of letters and numbers, where the numbers I actually want each have a unique string on the same line, but there is no real pattern to the rest of the file. Is there a faster way to read in non-uniformly formatted text files in MATLAB?

I tried using the code profiler in MATLAB to see what takes the most time, and it seemed to be the `strfind` and `strsplit` functions.  Deeper down, the `strfun\private\strescape` seems to be the culprit which takes up around 50% of the time, which is called by `strsplit` function.

I am currently using a combination of strfind and strsplit in order to search through a file for 5 specific strings, then convert the string after it into a double.

```
lots of text before this

   ####  unique identifying text here

lots of text before this

sometext  X = #####
          Y = #####
          Z = #####
more text = ######
```

I am iterating through the file with approximately the following code, repeated for each number that is being found.

```
fid=fopen(filename)
tline=fgets(fid)
while ischar(tline)
    if ~isempty(strfind(tline('X =')))
        tempstring=strsplit(tline(13:length(tline)),' ');
        result=str2double(char(tempstring(2)));
    end
    tline=fgets(fid);
end
```

Comment: `strsplit` returns a cell array, which are also notoriously slow. And I believe several string-manipulation functions have a bunch of overhead. Have you tried using `textscan`? Or even better: your python script?:)

Comment: Your way seems inefficient in general, but there's not much I could do to "compare" performance without an actual file. Do you have a copy you can link to?

Comment: also, am I correct in thinking you basically want the X Y and Z values?

Comment: I haven't tried textscan, doesn't it work well for files with regular sets of numbers? My file is not uniform, unfortunately.  I am not very clear on how to get MATLAB and Python to pass data to each other without writing to something like an hdf5.  It would be nice to be able to use the Python script though.

Comment: I do not have a copy I can link to, unfortunately, but you are correct that I want the x,y,z values.  However, there are a couple other values that I am trying to get as well. Each value that I want fortunately has a string which is unique to that line.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing this will be a bit faster, but maybe not by much.

```
s = fileread('texto');
[X,s] = strtok(strsplit(s, "X = "){2}); X = str2num(X);
[Y,s] = strtok(strsplit(s, "Y = "){2}); Y = str2num(Y);
[Z,s] = strtok(strsplit(s, "Z = "){2}); Z = str2num(Z);
```

Obviously this is highly specific to your text example. You haven't given me any more info on how the variables might change etc so presumably you'll have to implement `try/catch` blocks if files are not consistent etc.

PS. This is octave syntax which allows chaining operations. For matlab, split them into separate operations as appropriate.

**EDIT:** ach, nevermind, here's the matlab compatible one too. :)

```
s = fileread('texto');
C = strsplit(s, 'X = '); [X,s] = strtok(C{2}); X = str2num(X);
C = strsplit(s, 'Y = '); [Y,s] = strtok(C{2}); Y = str2num(Y);
C = strsplit(s, 'Z = '); [Z,s] = strtok(C{2}); Z = str2num(Z);
```

Comment: I was using this, which has worked well for the cases of `string` ####, but how do you adapt it to something like #### `string`? I do like how you read in the file as a string, and parse it once.

Comment: It's not clear to me what `string` #### / #### `string` means. Give an example. Preferably by revising your question to give specific examples of all your possible cases (otherwise the whole "ok A worked, no I have problem B; ok B worked now I have C" game isn't very fun :/ )

Comment: not to mention it's bad etiquette to hold an answer 'hostage' and keep [altering the deal](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WpE_xMRiCLE) :p

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou My record is getting to game D before I told the OP to politely f*** off and to ask a new question.  It was at that point where I'd go to at most game B before giving up.

Comment: hahah. ikr? Unfortunately I think there's rarely malice involved, so it's fair (and hopefully useful!) to point it out :p. It's just that, it seems the art of asking questions is lost on most people these days. Not to mention this worrying trend of caring less and less about the art of "how" to approach a problem, [and just going after ready "solutions" instead](http://www.haneycodes.net/npm-left-pad-have-we-forgotten-how-to-program/) :/  For me SO is all about the former, but I suspect for most "normal" people it's the latter :p